# Extract blocks of text that starts with "Start Text" until it encounters another "Start Text"

Tags: python

Here is the code I have to extract blocks of text of a file that starts with "Start Text" until it encounters another "Start Text".

```
 with open('temp.txt', "r") as f:
     buff = []
     i = 1
     for line in f:
         if line.strip():   skips the empty lines
             buff.append(line)
         if line.startswith("Start Text"):
             output = open('file' + '%d.txt' % i, 'w')
             output.write(''.join(buff))
             output.close()
             i += 1
             buff = []  # buffer reset
```

INPUT: "temp.txt" has the following structure:

```
Start Text - ABCD  
line1  
line2  
line3  
Start Text - EFG  
line4  
Start Text - P3456  
line5  
line6
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: I am trying to create multiple text files below with extracted blocks of texts.

**file1.txt**

```
Start Text - ABCD  
line1  
line2  
line3
```

**file2.txt**

```
Start Text - EFG  
line4
```

**file3.txt**

```
Start Text - P3456  
line5  
line6
```

UNDESIRED OUTPUT (What the code produces)

**file1.txt**

```
Start Text - ABCD
```

**file2.txt**

```
Start Text - EFG  
line1 
line2 
line3
```

**file3.txt**

```
line4 
Start Text - P3456
```

> Here is the issue I am facing. The code creates three files but does not write “Start Text” lines into their respective text blocks. I am not sure what I am missing. I will appreciate any pointers.

Comment: For one thing, the code is looking for "Sample ID", but the actual file has "Start Text".

Comment: Thanks for the correction

Comment: It would help if you updated the question to post the exact results you're seeing in the output files, and explain why those results aren't what you wanted.

Comment: It will create the first file with just the header and then the header will be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code sees "Start Text" in a line, it writes that line and all the *previous* lines to the output file.

This explains why the first output file contains only the header -- that is the first line in the input file, so obviously there aren't any *previous* lines.

It seems like what you really want is for the header and the *following* lines to be written.

I've updated your code to not write a file after seeing the *very first* header, and also to write a file after the input file is exhausted.

```
buff = []
i = 1

with open('temp.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Start Text"):
            # write a file only if buff isn't empty.  (if it is 
            # empty, this must be the very first header, so we
            # don't need to write an output file yet)
            if buff:
                output = open('file' + '%d.txt' % i, 'w')
                output.write(''.join(buff))
                output.close()
                i += 1
                buff = []  # buffer reset
        if line.strip():
            buff.append(line)

# write the final section
if buff:
    output = open('file' + '%d.txt' % i, 'w')
    output.write(''.join(buff))
    output.close()
```

Comment: I edited the question with the output I am getting. You are correct- I want the header and following lines until I encounter another header.

Comment: @DaveC See my updated answer with code.

Comment: This works. Thank you for your suggestions. I will upvote I again and accept the answer once I have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. See how when you check for `startswith()`, then write out the buffer, and clean the buffer. As it returns to the loop, if hasn't stored the line when entering this if statement - this line is lost. Try adding it to the new buffer for the next round of lines.

```py
             ...
             buff = []  # buffer reset
             buff.append(line) # add 'Start Text' line to next buffer
```

---

Note that your code currently will never write out the final block of text. Consider to write out the last buffer as well (i.e., when no line is left).

**[EDIT after question edit]**
As the other answer replies, the check for `startswith()` causes a write to file *after* the line is found. However, the line has already been added to the buffer. Try switching the statements, to first detect the `startswith`, then write everything out if it was the case (if the buffer is not empty!), then continue by adding the line to the buffer.
(the note still stands)

Comment: Let me give this a try. Adding buff.append(line) made it a little better, but it is still not what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to build a buffer. You can just process line by line as you iterate over the input file.

```
class MyTempFile():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fd = None
        self.newfile = None

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.closefd()
        self.newfile = None

    def closefd(self):
        if self.fd is not None:
            self.fd.close()
            self.fd = None

    def newfile_impl(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            self.closefd()
            i += 1
            self.fd = open(f'temp{i}.txt', 'w')
            yield

    def write(self, data):
        if self.fd is not None and data.strip():
            self.fd.write(data)

    def next_file(self):
        if self.newfile is None:
            self.newfile = self.newfile_impl()
        next(self.newfile)


with MyTempFile() as mtf:
    with open('temp.txt') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith('Start Text'):
                mtf.next_file()
            mtf.write(line)
```

Comment: This works, but it only creates only two files.

Comment: I have created a file with the data **exactly** as posted in your question and I get three files (as expected). Bear in mind that the test is case sensitive and I'm using *startswith()* so there mustn't be any whitespace preceding 'Start Text'

Comment: Now it works. I tend to avoid classes when I can, but this code looks beautiful. I will upvote upon building my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_file(fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        buff = []
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():   # skips the empty lines
                if line.startswith("Start Text") and buff:
                    yield ''.join(buff)
                    buff = []
                buff.append(line)


for idx, data in enumerate(parse_file('sample.txt'), start=1):
    with open(f'file{idx}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: This works as well. I will upvote when I have a few more reputations to cast a vote.